# EditText getText().toString() not working

Tags: android

I've been Googling for a while, but I can't find anything that solves my problem. I have some code in a nested fragment class that looks like this:

```
String infinitive;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        // Grabs input from text field and places it in String infinitive
        final EditText mMainTextField = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainTextField);
        infinitive = mMainTextField.getText().toString();

        final Button mConjugateButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.conjugateButton);
        mConjugateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean isEndingAr = infinitive.endsWith("ar");
                boolean isEndingEr = infinitive.endsWith("er");
                boolean isEndingIr = infinitive.endsWith("ir");

                // Check to see what kind of verb it is before conjugating
                if (isEndingAr) {
                    conjugateArVerb();
                } else if (isEndingEr) {
                    conjugateErVerb();
                } else if (isEndingIr) {
                    conjugateIrVerb();
                } else {
                    Toast testToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could not conjugate the verb: " + infinitive, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
```

My problem is that this line doesn't seem to be working:

```
infinitive = mMainTextField.getText().toString();
```

The testToast only returns "Could not conjugate: " not the value I input into the text field. I would post the XML file and the rest of the code in MainActivity.java, but I think this my problem is specifically with the getText().toString() line.

Please help me figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting `infinitive` to the value of the EditText content immediately after you instantiate the EditText object. However, you need it to obtain the value whenever the button is pressed because that's when you use the information.

So instead of this:

```
final EditText mMainTextField = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainTextField);
infinitive = mMainTextField.getText().toString();

// button listener
```

You should define `infinitive` inside the button listener, like this:

```
final EditText mMainTextField = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainTextField);

final Button mConjugateButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.conjugateButton);
mConjugateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        infinitive = mMainTextField.getText().toString();

        boolean isEndingAr = infinitive.endsWith("ar");
        boolean isEndingEr = infinitive.endsWith("er");
        boolean isEndingIr = infinitive.endsWith("ir");

        // ...
```

Comment: All of the other answers are the same as this one and are great! I wish I could upvote all of them, but thanks to everyone! The answer was much simpler than I thought.

Comment: @awkwardgiraffe You now have the reputation to upvote the answers you think are useful.

Answer (score 1):

Move:

```
infinitive = mMainTextField.getText().toString();
```

into the `onClick()` method. Right now, it will be empty, because the user has not typed anything by the time you execute that statement, microseconds after the `EditText` was created.

Answer (score 1):

When you are executing this line `infinitive = mMainTextField.getText().toString();` the user hasn't had the chance to enter anything in the `EditText`. The click event is the moment when you are sure that the user wants you to *read that value*. Moving that line to inside that method should fix it.