# getText().toString() not working, returns empty

Tags: android, android-edittext, filewriter

I'm trying to save `userName` but the saved text file always returns `, 6`. How can I get it to show whatever value of userName entered into `EditText`, and the rest? for example `Don, 6`. I have read you have to use `getText()` but that isn't returning anything in the saved file.

However, if I replace `6` with an intent to receive score from previous activity, this works! like this...

```
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int score = extras.getInt("Score");
```

So this becomes...

```
public void addListenerToEndButton() {

    quit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.endBtn);
    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int score = extras.getInt("score");

    quit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        String strName = userName.getText().toString();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveProgress(strName + ", " + score, "results.txt");
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```

But it still returns `empty, whatever score is`. For example `, 4`.

I've read this post that suggests it should be inside onClickListener which it is:
[EditText getText().toString() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838644/edittext-gettext-tostring-not-working)

This is my `saveProgress` class:

```
public void saveProgress(String contents, String fileName) {

    try {
        File fp = new File(this.getFilesDir(), fileName);
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(fp);
        out.append(contents);
        out.append("\n\r");
        out.close();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Me","file error:" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't the problem that you are retrieving the text of the edittext outside of the onclick method? try moving it inside the onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onClick()` method with the following:

```
public void addListenerToEndButton() {
  quit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.endBtn);
  userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);

  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  int score = extras.getInt("score");

  quit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String strName = userName.getText().toString();
        saveProgress(strName + ", " + score, "results.txt");
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
  });
}
```

Calls, initializations, operations, exc, should go inside the `onClick` method of the listener. The `onClick` is fired only when the button is clicked, everything outside the `onClick` but inside the `Listener` is called on `Listener` initialization

Comment: Thank you, such a simple overlook. I understand it now. I know this is outside scope of question, but do you have any ideas why it is overwriting the file instead of appending into that text file as a new line? I've attempted it in `saveProgress` class.

Comment: @kamil1995b honestly i don't know, but consider looking at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542318/android-append-text-file) :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you understood 'inside onClickListener' wrong. What you are doing atm is that you read `strName` when you create the listener, but I guess you want to read it when `quit` is clicked.

So just move the line into the function and the value will be correct.

```
public void addListenerToEndButton() {

    quit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.endBtn);
    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);

    quit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strName = userName.getText().toString();
            saveProgress(strName + ", " + 6, "results.txt");
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```